# What is the Best/Stronger authentication system to use in ionic v4 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working on an ionic app which start with a login system, I already create a basic authentication system which fetch in the database for the username and the password if exist I get as output the ID of the user and his full name and I store them in the local storage but I can see that this way isn't secure enough so how I can build a strong and a secure authentication system using ionic 4v, I found something like using a token and store but i didn't get the idea

Note : for the Backend there is an other team works on it they use JEE with SpringBoot Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest going with the `JSON Web Token (JWT)` approach. You can find more information on it [here](https://jwt.io/). You basically want to create an API endpoint that consumes the users username and password then validates it and if it is successful it returns a JWT.

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard (RFC 7519) that defines a
>   compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information
>   between parties as a JSON object. This information can be verified and
>   trusted because it is digitally signed. JWTs can be signed using a
>   secret (with the HMAC algorithm) or a public/private key pair using
>   RSA or ECDSA.

You might also want to include refresh tokens so that you can get a new JWT when the current one expires as putting a long expiry on a JWT [is not recommended](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180017/importance-of-a-short-expire-time-on-jwts).

You will need to provide more information on what programming language your backend/API is in so that we can assist you with the correct implementation thereof.

Comment: Thank you! for the backend we use the JEE programming language with spring boot framework